# Align nav-item bottom border with navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Is there a way to align the bottom border of a bootstrap nav-item with the bottom border of the navbar? I want to use the bottom border to show which element is selected. I was able to do this, with the default height of the navbar. Once I increase the `height` to`80px` the bottom border is not aligned anymore.

[image: bottom border not aligned]

Html:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNav"
      aria-controls="navbarNav"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#"
            >Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

and the CSS:

```
     <style>
      .navbar {
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .navbar-nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }

      .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3rem;
      }

      .navbar-nav .nav-link.active::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -2px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #007bff;
      }
    </style>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `bottom` css from -2px to -17px for .navbar-nav .nav-link.active::after (The blue bar). (I also added `navbar-expand-md` and `navbar-expand-sm` so you can see the menu open on the snippet I made containing your code).

```css
.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px; /*adjust this*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a
          >
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          <div class="narrow-bar"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```